# Can a HBITMAP contains alpha channel information?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, gdi+

I notice `ICONINFO` contains two bitmap. If I understand correctrly, `hbmMask` is for the icon's outline which at the same time specifies which part should be transparent, and `hbmColor` is for the icon's actual color `HBITMAP`.

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648052(v=vs.85).aspx
- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/490fb15a-61a5-4a5d-a1a0-fed675975293/hbmmask-hbmcolor-in-iconinfo?forum=vcgeneral

So My question is, why the `hbmMask` is necessary? Why not just put the alpha channel's information inside `hbmColor`? Is it able to combine them into a single bitmap?

Besides, `Gdiplus::Bitmap` has a [constructor which accepts a HICON](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms536318(v=vs.85).aspx) . Does it mean this GDI+ bitmap is able to handle alpha channel information?

Thanks:)

Comment: You are asking the wrong question. Yes, bitmaps can store alpha channels. However, with the exception of `AlphaBlend` (and maybe a few others), the GDI does not honor the alpha channel. In essence, bitmaps support alpha channels, but the API does not. Besides that, [icon files can store PNG images with an alpha channel](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20101022-00/?p=12473), so no mask is required there.

Comment: @IInspectable The question is tagged GDI+ which actually respects the alpha channel. Also PNG format is not required for an icon file to support alpha channel. Any 32 bpp image in the icon can have an alpha channel. PNG is just for optional compression.

Comment: @zett42: The question is asking about `ICONINFO`, `HBITMAP`, and `HICON`. Those are data types in the Windows API, not GDI+. While you can dump a 32bpp bitmap into an icon file, [you are still required to add a mask](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20101021-00/?p=12483/), even if you are using the alpha channel. This is different for PNG icons, where no mask is in the icon file.

Comment: @IInspectable Thanks for the links, I have corrected my answer. Still OP explicitly asked about `Gdiplus::Bitmap` constructor that accepts a `HICON`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why the hbmMask is necessary? Why not just put the alpha channel's
>   information inside hbmColor?

An alpha channel is only possible for 32 bpp bitmaps (8 bit alpha channel, 8 bit red, green and blue channels each). Icons with 1 to 8 bpp bitmaps therefore have to store the transparency information separately from the color bitmap in the `hbmMask` bitmap.

Actually, even 32 bpp bitmaps that have an alpha channel, [are required to include the `hbmMask`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20101021-00/?p=12483/), [unless the PNG format is used](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20101022-00/?p=12473). In the latter case, the mask is derived automatically from the alpha channel.

> Besides, Gdiplus::Bitmap has a constructor which accepts a HICON .
>   Does it mean this GDI+ bitmap is able to handle alpha channel
>   information?

As the documentation doesn't state otherwise, you are safe to assume that the constructor converts a 32 bpp `HICON` into a 32 bpp bitmap. A GDI+ bitmap certainly is able to store an alpha channel if the pixel format is appropriate (in the case of an icon [`PixelFormat32bppARGB`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms534412(v=vs.85).aspx) is required).

Comment: Do you happen to have an example of setting the alpha info in a `HBITMAP`?

Comment: @hackjutsu Once you have a GDI+ bitmap with an alpha channel, you could call `Gdiplus::Graphics *g = Gdiplus::Graphics::FromImage(&bitmap);` and then use `Graphics` methods to manipulate the alpha channel.